# iOS:I use xib with `autolayout` to create a`uiview`, set it to a tableview's header,there comes a strange issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints, xib

This bellow is my code:

```
    /* searchBar */
    lml_search = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LMLSearchHeadView" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = lml_search;
```

And in my `xib`, I set a `backview` which is on the `xib`'s view, I set 4 `constraints` for `backview` space to `xib`'s view.

At the `viewcontroller1` first show, it was normal, but after the `viewcontroller1` push to `viewcontroller2`, and pop to `viewcontroller1`, the `lml_search`'s height become `0`! 
    This code can prove me:

```
(lldb) po lml_search
<LMLSearchHeadView: 0x7f9c1e33f4e0; frame = (0 0; 320 0); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9c1e33d980>>
```

I don't know why it comes for my project.

Comment: have you given height and width constraint to backview?

Comment: @User31 I did not. but I set `Trailling, Leading, Bottom, Top` spacing for my `backview`.  ( its superview is xib's view)

Comment: are you setting frame of lml_search or height of tableHeaderView?

Comment: I did not set height of`tableHeaderView`, is this reason?

Comment: Set the height of tableHeaderView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, but I must set the `xib's` view frame in the `viewWillAppear:`:

```
[lml_search setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kScreen_Width, 44)];
```

But I don't know the real reason of this issue.